# How can i install all my apps in other phones at once

Tags: applications, google-play-store, installation, bootloader, downloading

I am an app developers , I also work on phones, How can i install all my apps into my customers phones at once. Instead of installing each one by one.

is there a faster method through which I can install all 10 of my apps with one click?

Comment: Is enabling USB Debugging an option? If so, you can easily write a small shell script to install all apps in sequence (basic `adb install`).

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there's no way to do this. Since every app installation should go through the [Systems Permissions](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html) check regardless if the user is the same, if the device is different.

In order for the installation to proceed, the user of the phone **MUST** grant access to if first. This is a security matter and will always be applied.

Comment: PS: If this is more about a developer issue, I think you should post it on [StackOverflow](https://www.stackoverflow.com) instead. Would still provide this answer over there though.